# <eof> expected near 'end'

Tags: lua, eof, game-development

I'm using these files in my gaming server, and every time I add a new player model, I get

[image: this error]

```
[ERROR] lua/autorun/server/fastdlskins.lua:938: '<eof>' expected near 'end'
  1. unknown - lua/autorun/server/fastdlskins.lua:0
```

I also get a similar error when I add an add-on to a different file

[image: img]

```
 [ERROR] lua/autorun/server/workshopitems.lua:55: '<eof>' expected near 'end'
   1. unknown - lua/autorun/server/workshopitems.lua:0
```

I usually just have to put an 'end' after the code, but I don't see what else I'm required to do. I don't have any loops running (I think), so I'm not closing any of those out. Not sure what to do.

Comment: it sounds like you have a spurious `end` somewhere in one or both of those scripts. without seeing the content of those scripts, nobody can help you.

Comment: You are barely displaying 50 * 2 lines out of atleast 900

Comment: I did a ctrl+F to search for any "end"s in the both scripts, and came back with only 1 for each, which rests at the bottom of both scripts. I've got both scripts here: http://pastebin.com/9H7CaRR2 and http://pastebin.com/BFnwsiWB

Comment: Why are you finishing each Lua script with additional `end`?  Just remove these `end`s.

Comment: thank you. I removed the 'end's I had written out. Now I'm getting new errors, but are easily fixable. So far I've found I've written 'resources' instead of 'resource' and a couple of minor errors like that. Well, that one less error I have to keep seeing from now on. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Egor said, remove the extra `end` at the end of the files.

`end` is only used to close blocks for functions and loops, like `}` in C-like languages. The `end` at the file is not closing anything, and is thus invalid syntax.

Comment: Thanks! I removed them, and now we're good. Looking for any other errors that pop up, now that that error is gone.